I am trying to launch my motoko project (WSL) but vscode don't run. what can i do to resolve the problem?
The vscode window open but nothing is visible  image of vscode windows when i tried to open it
I have tried to restart the vscode windows and launch with administrator privilege
I have also tried to restart my computer and launch my project directly via the ubuntu console

run code --verbose --log trace and see if there's any info about what's wrong
